# Web script to get the parameters of the document

Tags: java, alfresco, freemarker

Create a web script to get the parameters of the document in java

Example url

```
localhost:8080/alfresco/s/get-document-data?nodeRef=workspace://SpacesStore/3b3597e5-b5ec-41d5-b63b-54b050dccd1b&property=cm:name
```

For implementation we use NodeService

```
nodeService.getProperty (new NodeRef (nodeRef), LmrContentModel.getQname (property));
```

As a result the script should return Json object of a kind

```
{
"nodeRef": "workspace: // SpacesStore / 3b3597e5-b5ec-41d5-b63b-54b050dccd1b",
"value": "value property - the one we got from nodRef"
}
```

Create a web script to retrieve all subfolder settings along the way.
Please help!

Comment: What isn't working? The code you have posted doesn't look like a complete webscript, what code have you written and where are you getting stuck?

Comment: how to get this line: nodeService.NodeRef(new NodeRef(nodeRef), LmrContentModel.getQname(property));  json with document properties and get all subfolder settings as specified.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SimpleWebScript extends AbstractWebScript {
    @Override
    public void execute(WebScriptRequest req, WebScriptResponse res)  throws IOException {
        try {
            List<ChildAssociationRef> nodeRef = nodeService.getChildAssocs(companyHomeRef);
            for (ChildAssociationRef childAssoc : nodeRef) {
                NodeRef childNodeRef = childAssoc.getChildRef();
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                obj.put("nodeRef", childAssoc);
                obj.put("value", childAssoc.getQName());
                String jsonString = obj.toString();
                res.getWriter().write(jsonString);
                ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = (ServiceRegistry) context.getBean("ServiceRegistry");
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            throw new WebScriptException("Unable to serialize JSON");

        }
    }
}

<beans>
    <bean id="webscript.org.alfresco.simple.get"
          class="org.alfresco.repository.SimpleWebScript"
          parent="webscript">
    </bean>
</beans>

<webscript>
<shortname>Document</shortname>
<description></description>
<url>/demoSimple?nodeRef={nodeRef}&amp;attach={attach?}</url>
<format default="json"></format>
<authentication>user</authentication>
<family>Alfresco Document</family>
</webscript>
```

Here I want to get the parameters of the document here is the code but it doesn't work, what's wrong with it?

Comment: Update your Question and include your code there. Not as the Answer